# Is it possible to include the version number in the name of a Github Action?

Tags: github-actions

When running an action, one can give a name given to the action in YAML. When auto-running a workflow, based on the published action, Github automatically attaches the release version to the title. I would like to do something similar when manually releasing. Is that possible?

E.g.
[image]

YAML start for PROD release:

```
name: 'Prod - Deploy Tag or Latest Release'

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
```

YAML for STAGE release:

```
name: 'Stage - AUTO - Deploy Latest Release'

on:
  release:
    types: [published]
  workflow_dispatch:
```

To recap, I would like the Prod release to have the version number attached to the title in the same way that it is on the Stage release.